# What's the best way to study the exact color code used by app UI

Tags: android

Sometime, I would like to know what is the color code used by an app UI. (Without accessing to its XML resource file)

I simply do this, by capture screenshot of a device (Pressing power button + volume button simultaneously). I would then, use Paint.NET, and perform color picker on the captured screenshot.

I realize that, by using this methodology is not accurate. For instance, I'm pretty sure a pure white is being used for a background. However, when I perform color picking operation, I realize `#fff3f3f3` is being returned, where I'm expecting `#ffffffff`. (I'm using nexus s)

I think this may vary from different devices. I was wondering, what is the most accurate way to study color code used by an app UI?

p/s Nowasday app market is extremely competitive. Every single details, even up to atom level does matter in order to win over the race :)

Comment: Your eye won't see the difference between `#ffffff` and `#fff3f3f3` so maybe the latter is correct ?

Comment: imo is kind of impossible to have the exact hex that was used.   Screenshot are compressed (jpeg - if I recall correctly) and those alghoritm are not lossy

Comment: @Flawyte I'm pretty sure the value suppose to be `#ffffffff` as I'm the author of the app :)

Comment: Black belt is right. The image is compressed, so it loses information. Try capturing the screen using DDMS in Eclipse.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng That's a good argument.

Comment: If you get the screenshot inside your app (by code - **setDrawingCache(true);** - you know what I mean) and then save it as a **PNG**, then you won't loose any bit of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the app in an emulator, make a screenshot of your computer, and paste it into your favorite image editor. Now you should have exact colors available for examination.